# How to set listview item height when items in listview are different heights themselves

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview  that I need to set the height of, but in the strings I use `\n` to create line breaks, and when these are in the listview, it messes with the final height of the view, making the text in the bottom one or two items get cut off from view.

Basically the code below isn't working for listviews containing rows of different heights. it only appears to base its height off the height of the first row, multiplied by the amount of rows there are.

Here is the standard code I'm using to get my listview height set:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: It's weird that the calculated height is wrong, but why are you doing this in the first place ? If you want to have other view at the top or bottom of the listview, you can use headerView or footerView.

Comment: The listview is in the middle of a moderately complex layout. I'm using the listview as a method of displaying data more efficiently than a tableview. Also the fact that I there may be a different amount of rows depending on what variables there are earlier in the code, a listview is more dynamic for me to use :)

Comment: Ok, but calculating the height makes you inflate all the views (without recycling them). If you have 100 items, you are creating 100 times the view just to get the height. You could as well remove the listview, keep the creation of the all the views and add them directly to a LinearLayout which is in your main ScrollView between the top and bottom stuff.

Comment: the data is inserted into the listview via 2 string arrays. Not sure how i could convert this into a linearlayout. May I add that it is a RelativeLayout in my scrollview, not a linearlayout :)

Comment: Well, instead of placing a ListView you put a LinearLayout. Then by code you iterate through your string array, you inflate a view from your xml layout, then set the value of the TextView that is probably inside, and then you take the LinearLayout and call addView() with the inflated view, and go on for each string.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Do you have a link to an example of this in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already populate all the views, you should replace the ListView with a LinearLayout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- top -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- fake listview -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- bottom -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And the code :

```
    LinearLayout llList = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_list);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);        
    String[] data = new String[] {"1","2","3"};     

    for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
    {
        View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null); //same layout you gave to the adapter       

        TextView tv = (TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv.setText(data[i]);

        llList.addView(inflater.inflate(R.id.sepatator, null)); // if you want a separator can be a simple view with a line and margins
        llList.addView(childView);
    }
```

For the separator you can use this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#555" >
</View>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm getting errors related to the seperator. Where should this be defined? thanks

Comment: This is all working perfectly, and I will mark as accepted, but do you know how to fix up the seperator? thank you very much!

Comment: I've added something for the separator.